# Executing queries doesn't alter Heroku postgreSQL DB

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, heroku, psycopg2

I'm using `psycopg2` python3 library to connection to my heroku postgreSQL database. Heroku provided me with database url, I store it in `DATABASE_URL` environmental variable. I'm trying to locally connect to DB and execute some queries. But it seems like executing queries doesn't affect on heroku database, example:

```python
import psycopg2, os

DATABASE_URL = os.getenv('DATABASE_URL')
conn = psycopg2.connect(DATABASE_URL, sslmode='require')
cur = conn.cursor()
    
cur.execute("CREATE TABLE chat (id int, chat_name TEXT);")
cur.execute("""
            INSERT INTO chat (id, chat_name) VALUES
                (1, 'name1'),
                (2, 'name2');
            """)
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM chat;")
print(cur.fetchall())
conn.close()
```

It prints:

```
>>> [(1, 'name1'), (2, 'name2')]
```

Then I'm trying to execute following code:

```python
import psycopg2, os

DATABASE_URL = os.getenv('DATABASE_URL')
conn = psycopg2.connect(DATABASE_URL, sslmode='require')
cur = conn.cursor()
    
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM chat")
print(cur.fetchall())
conn.close()
```

But it throws error:

```
>>> psycopg2.errors.UndefinedTable: relation "chat" does not exist
>>> LINE 1: SELECT * FROM chat;
```

Seems like table wasn't saved after executing creation and insertion queries. How to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is the table was created and the values inserted into it within the session created by `conn = psycopg2.connect(DATABASE_URL, sslmode='require')` and `conn.close()`. As long as you stayed in that session(did not `close()`) everything would be there. The lack of `conn.commit()` meant the table and data did not persist past the `conn.close()`, nor was it observable by any other concurrent sessions. You need to `commit()` to persist the changes or set [autocommit](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/connection.html#connection.autocommit).

Answer (score 1):

Table wasn't creating and values weren't inserted because there was no `conn.commit()` before `conn.close()`. There's an paragraph with example in **psycopg** documentation: 
https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#basic-module-usage